# JQuery Script Preventing Gridview Paging from firing more than once

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have an issue where I can page the first time with my gridview but when I try to click on the second page, nothing happens.  I've been able to pinpoint that it has to do with a JQuery script that is used to tab to the next textbox after an OnTextChanged event is fired within my gridview which works like a charm. First, here is the relevant code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerDetails" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var g_CurrentTextBox;                
            Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);
            function applicationLoadHandler() {
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
            }

            function endRequestHandler() {

                $get(g_CurrentTextBox).focus();
                $get(g_CurrentTextBox).select();
            }


            function onTextFocus() {
                g_CurrentTextBox = event.srcElement.id;
            }                
        </script>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDetails" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="row" id="ItemResults">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvDetailList" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDetailList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvDetailList_RowDataBound" Pagesize="25" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText ="Item Number" SortExpression="ItemNumber" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="QUANTITY">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblGVQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QUANTITY") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuantity" runat="server">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" 
                                      AutoPostBack="true"  Text='<%#Eval("QUANTITY") %>' OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvQuantity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Type="Integer" ForeColor="Red"
                                 Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Quantity is not numeric" Text="* Quantity is not numeric" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="valAdd" />
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDetailList" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionStr%>"                     
             >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDetails();
    }
}

private void BindDetails()
{        
    string strSQL = "SELECT  * FROM TABLE";
    SqlDetailList.SelectCommand = strSQL;
    gvDetailList.DataSource = SqlDetailList;
    gvDetailList.DataBind();
}

protected void gvDetailList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{        
    gvDetailList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindDetails();
}
```

If I remove the script, paging works fine.  But I like I said, with the script left in, it only works the first time but not on subsequent pages.

Comment: Is there a JavaScript exception in the console?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: Have I stumped everyone? Haha.  But in all seriousness, any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it working now after making some changes.  First I made some changes to the JQuery script by looking to see if the current Textbox is null or not and whether the gridview count is the same as it was before the page request.  This is because for some reason if I'm on the fifth row of a page and the next page only has four rows, then it would be looking to put the focus on the fifth row of the page and I would get an exception.

Then for the code behind, I simply put the focus on the first row in the Page_Load event and PageIndexChanged event (which I added).

HTML:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerDetails" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rowscountbefore;
        var g_CurrentTextBox;                
        Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);
        function applicationLoadHandler() {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
        }

        function beginRequestHandler() {
        rowscountbefore = $("#<%=gvDetailList.ClientID%> tr").length;
         }

        function endRequestHandler() {
         if (g_CurrentTextBox != null && rowscountbefore == $("#<%=gvDetailList.ClientID%> tr").length) {
            $get(g_CurrentTextBox).focus();
            $get(g_CurrentTextBox).select();
           }
        }

        function onTextFocus() {
            g_CurrentTextBox = event.srcElement.id;
        }                
    </script>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDetails" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="row" id="ItemResults">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvDetailList" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" OnPageIndexChanged="gvDetailList_PageIndexChanged"
          AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDetailList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvDetailList_RowDataBound" Pagesize="25" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText ="Item Number" SortExpression="ItemNumber" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="QUANTITY">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblGVQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QUANTITY") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuantity" runat="server">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" 
                                  AutoPostBack="true"  Text='<%#Eval("QUANTITY") %>' OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvQuantity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Type="Integer" ForeColor="Red"
                             Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Quantity is not numeric" Text="* Quantity is not numeric" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="valAdd" />
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDetailList" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionStr%>"                     
         >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDetails();
        TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)gvDetailList.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQuantity");
        txtQuantity.Focus();
    }
}

private void BindDetails()
{        
    string strSQL = "SELECT  * FROM TABLE";
    SqlDetailList.SelectCommand = strSQL;
    gvDetailList.DataSource = SqlDetailList;
    gvDetailList.DataBind();
}

protected void gvDetailList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{        
    gvDetailList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindDetails();
}

protected void gvDetailList_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)gvDetailList.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("txtQuantity");
    txtQuantity.Focus();
}
```